# How to avoid union all

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Any possibility methods to avoiding "Union all" when different joining > conditions varies on each section

```
SELECT RS1.*, EXL.*
            FROM "EXL" "EXL"
      INNER JOIN "RS1" "RS1"
              ON "RS1"."HEADER_KEY" = "EXL"."HEADER_KEY"
WHERE "RS1"."PIPE_KEY" = '1109' AND
     "RS1"."COLK" IS NULL  AND
     "RS1".CT1 = 0  AND  "RS1".CT2 > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT RS1.*, EXL.*
            FROM "EXL" "EXL"
      INNER JOIN "RS1" "RS1"
              ON "RS1"."HEADER_KEY" = "EXL"."HEADER_KEY"
      INNER JOIN "YFS"."STATUS_MAP" "SOS"
              ON "SOS"."STATUS" = "RS1"."STATUS"
      INNER JOIN "RS1" "RS2"
              ON "RS2"."LINE_KEY" = "RS1"."CHAINLINE_KEY" AND
                 "RS2"."PIPEKEY" = "SOS"."TYPE_KEY" AND
                 "RS2"."STATUS" = "SOS"."EXTN_STATUS" AND
                 "RS2"."PIPE_KEY" = '4093'
WHERE "RS1"."PIPE_KEY" = '1109' AND
      "RS1"."COLK" IS NULL  AND
      "RS1".CT1 = 0  AND  "RS1".CT2 > 0
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the union all? Have you considered that this may be the most performant option? What evidence have you gathered that this is a problem? Can you show it to us?

Comment: Also, what does the second query accomplish? It is either a subset of the first query, or duplicates records in the first query.  Either way, unioning it to the first query only ever duplicates rows you're already fetching. Is that your correct intention?

Answer (score 0):

Since the two SELECTs have exactly the same WHERE-condition, I assume that you want to return rows from `EXL`, even when rows from `YFS.STATUS_MAP` are missing (otherwise please explain what your intention is). You can do this with [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php)

```
SELECT RS1.*, EXL.*
FROM
    "EXL"
    INNER JOIN "RS1"
        ON "RS1"."HEADER_KEY" = "EXL"."HEADER_KEY"
    LEFT JOIN "YFS"."STATUS_MAP" "SOS"
        ON "SOS"."STATUS" = "RS1"."STATUS"
    LEFT JOIN "RS1" "RS2"
        ON "RS2"."LINE_KEY" = "RS1"."CHAIN_LINE_KEY" AND
           "RS2"."PIPEKEY" = "SOS"."TYPE_KEY" AND
           "RS2"."STATUS" = "SOS"."EXTN_STATUS" AND
           "RS2"."PIPELINE_KEY" = '4093'
WHERE "RS1"."PIPELINE_KEY" = '1109' AND
      "RS1"."COLK" IS NULL  AND
      "RS1".CT1 = 0  AND  "RS1".CT2 > 0
```

Comment: I want to avoid completely because of RS1 is a very big table

Comment: This does not explain why you did use UNION ALL in the first place. Your SQL duplicates some rows and never selects columns from SOS and RS2. Why it it join them then? I do not see the meaning behind it.